# Put values of a foreach loop inside a div

Tags: php, html, css

```
   <?php
    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'projet'));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
            echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
          }
        if (has_excerpt($recent["ID"]) ){
            // echo get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt');
            echo '<p class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt') . '</p>';
          }
    }
?>
```

Hi, I would like to know how to put all my `foreach` loop inside a div ? I want each `$recent_posts` to be inside a div, right now they're one after the other. (btw it's my first post here, excuse me if i'm not clear)

**##EDIT##
Here's my html :**

```html
<h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/projet/projet-3/" title="Look Maquette UX/UI">Maquette UX/UI</a></h2> <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/vignette_maquette-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image"
  alt="" loading="lazy" />
<p class="excerpt">Projet 1</p>
<h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/projet/projet-2/" title="Look Intégration Baniera">Intégration Baniera</a></h2> <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/vignette_baniera_homepage-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image"
  alt="" loading="lazy" />
<p class="excerpt">Projet 2</p>
<h2><a href="http://localhost/wordpress/projet/projet-1/" title="Look Intégration PHP">Intégration PHP</a></h2> <img width="150" height="150" src="http://localhost/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/order_homepage-150x150.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail wp-post-image"
  alt="" loading="lazy" />
<p class="excerpt">Projet 3</p>
<p class="excerpt"></p>
</div>
```

**And I want every "group" to be inside a div, right now they're all together**

Ok it works now, I wrapped the content of `foreach` like so :

```
<?php
$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'projet'));
foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
    echo '<div class="foreach_wrapper">';

    echo '<h2><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a></h2> ';
    if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
        echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
      }
    if (has_excerpt($recent["ID"]) ){
        // echo get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt');
        echo '<p class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt') . '</p>';
      }

    echo '</div>';
}
```

?>

Comment: Hi Juan, can you post the resulting HTML of what you have now, and an example of what you'd wish your result would be?

Comment: @juan what result you want? and what is current result?

Comment: I just edited my post

Comment: I see `echo '<li>...` - And `LI` elements can't have siblings other then `LI`s

Comment: @Juan Do you want to add each para and heading under separate `div` or complete existing body structure under `div`?

Comment: I would like to put heading + para inside a common div @Andy And I will correct the li element thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can echo a div around the foreach, a little side note, you are using a `<li>` element but forgot the `<ul>` wrapper please validate your HTML with a HTML validator.

```
   <?php
    echo '<div>'; /* I added this */

    $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts(array('post_type'=>'projet'));
    foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        
        echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '" title="Look '.esc_attr($recent["post_title"]).'" >' .   $recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
        if ( has_post_thumbnail( $recent["ID"]) ) {
            echo  get_the_post_thumbnail($recent["ID"],'thumbnail');
          }
        if (has_excerpt($recent["ID"]) ){
            // echo get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt');
            echo '<p class="excerpt">' . get_the_excerpt($recent["ID"],'the_excerpt') . '</p>';
          }
    }

    echo '</div>'; /* I added this */

?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that !